# Tagged PDF file created using iText7 is huge in size when compared to other PDF creation API.is there any workaround to reduce that?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I have created a Tagged PDF file with 10k pages,using iText7.The file size is atleast 3 times larger than the same file created using pdfbox API.I have already set WritterProperties.setFullCompressionMode to true.is there anyother workaround to reduce the file size further?

Comment: My PDF has 31 pages, only text (table), and is more than 10 times larger than the one using iTextSharp (iText5). The iText7 version has table header that appear in each page. Only difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you can offer the tagged PDF in some other alternative accessible format such as .csv or .txt, these are inherently accessible by design. I would say that would be the workaround for now.